# Is every continuous function on $\mathbb R$ the pointwise limit of a sequence of polynomials?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I was thinking if the following is true

> Is every continuous function on $\mathbb R$ the pointwise limit of a sequence of polynomials?

This seems to be something that shouldn't be too hard to answer but I have managed to get my self stuck

**Thoughts:** My initial thought was that I should partition $\mathbb{R}$ in some way and then make use of the Stone-Weistruass theorem. I don't need uniform convergence but it should give me atleast pointwise. I thought about using intervals of the form $[-n,n]$ or $[n,n+1]$ but my arguments failed.

I briefly considerered the taylor series of a convolution of a gaussian density but this turned to no avail.

I tried to also look for counter examples. In doing so, I was looking for some property of pointwise limits of polynomials but I couldn't find one.

Lastly, I had the idea to use interpolation and get, in the limit, interpolation of countably many points. This runs in the issue that I may have Gibs phenomenon where I get too much noice between interpolation points which ruins my approximation.

**Question:** How does one approach to thinking about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a continuous function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, the Stone-Weierstrass theorem implies that for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$, there is a polynomial $f_n$ such that, for all $x \in [-n, n]$, $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < 1/n$. The $f_n$ comprise a sequence of polynomials that converge pointwise to $f$.

Comment: It suffices to refer to the Weierstrass theorem. There is no need of applying the SW theorem.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: yes, Weierstrass's result on this topic is all that one needs. However, Weierstrass has quite a lot of theorems to his name (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_theorem), so it's quicker to add in Stone if you want to identify the result about approximation by polynomials.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc By what logic should Weierstrass get to co-author a general result he did not work on AND to be cited alone for the special case? Why be mean to Stone? ;)

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I consider the Weierstrass approximation theorem more elementary than SW theorem, but this is a matter of personel taste. Another reason is that the approximating  polynomials can be given explicitly  applying the Bernstein polynomials.